# Max retries exceeded while using rotating proxy with Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, imgur

I'm currently working with an Imgur Bot using Python and requests lib with a rotating proxy. I run multiple instances of this bot, but sometimes, some of them got this error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.imgur.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/credits (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

Here is how the session is defined:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.proxies = {"http": cre["Proxy"]}
```

I have no idea why it crashes since only a part instances I run got this error. The others work well.

Thanks, mates!

Comment: can you try formatting your proxies like this {proxy_type:"http://{proxy}"}

Comment: @Hans it is actually in this form now

Comment: The error is self-explanatory itself `Cannot connect to proxy.` and edit your post include whole code. `session.proxies = {"http": cre["Proxy"]} <- isn't imgur https

Comment: @Hans the point is, I have multiple instances running at once, but only a few of them crashed. If that was a proxy problem, all the instances would crash, wouldn't they?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your proxies are wrong configurated?

I think you run into some form of "requesting too much too fast".

Try to delay some requests (like 3 seconds).

Comment: well, in each instance, it will delay about a minute between each request

Comment: How many instances are running? 

And it’s always the same proxy’s which are crashing?